# Create a table for each entry in a model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am new to python and django, I Want to add a table dynamically in the database when a new user register (in python way of course), in other words when a user inserts a new data into a model i want to create a table explicitly for that entry, to add extra Data which will related with that entry.

I think python has an easy way to handle this kind of situation

Thank You.

[Image representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWyYX.png)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to have 2 tables: Users and Todos. `User` model already exists in Django if only you don't want to write a custom user, so what you have to add is Todos model

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

```
Class Todo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='todos')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)   
    note = models.TextField()
```

When you have `john`, `alen`, `bob` user with id `1,2,3` you can have:

```
john = User.objects.get(id=1)
alen = User.objects.get(id=2)
bob = User.objects.get(id=3)
```

Let's create `Todo` for `alen` according to your schema:

```
Todo.objects.create(user=alen, name='visit', note='Visit Doc.')
Todo.objects.create(user=alen, name='Buy', note='Buy Radio')
```

Let's create `Todo` for `john`  according to your schema:

```
Todo.objects.create(user=john, name='pay bill', note='some large text')
Todo.objects.create(user=john, name='watch Dog', note='detail')
Todo.objects.create(user=john, name='play game', note='detail')
```

Let's create `Todo` for `bob`  according to your schema:

```
Todo.objects.create(user=bob, name='call', note='call John')
Todo.objects.create(user=bob, name='Meet', note='meet jane')
```

In order to get `Todo` of particular user, for example for `bob` you can have:

```
bob_todos = Todo.objects.filter(user=bob)
```

or

```
bob_todos = bob.todos.all()
```

according to `related_name`

Comment: Thanks for lookup, But bro I want to create a separate table for each user. Because ToDo table will be HUGE, if it contains every users Todo information, which will take more load time to query from the database.

Comment: @Ahadul, that's a bad design. There is 99,99% chance that your app will be a complete failure, but if it does make it, you'll end up with millions of tables, most will be practically empty. Database like this will be impossible to maintain and you won't be able to analyze users at all. And HUGE starts at say 1TB. Generate 1 million random tasks and check table size to get an approximate idea how many tasks/users you need to get to 1/10/100/1000 GB.

Comment: Ok @Borut. thank you first, for your comment. If i have 2000 user, and i want to collect there login/attendance in a single table, what you think, which will be the best thing to do in this case. suppose every user login once a day, that mean everyday database will get 2000 entry. i think within 1 month table size will be HUGE. Please share you oppenioun

Comment: @Ahadul, don't worry, that's not huge by today's standards. Just have one table for all todos and similarly one table for all users activities. Login timestamp, user id and primary key will be about 50 bytes per row. With 2000 rows per day that's about 100kb daily and 3 MB monthly. It'll take you about 330 months or 27 years to reach a size of 1GB (20 million rows) and that is actually small.